# How can I self-aim eyedrops more accurately?

Tags: health

My HYLO eyedrops are dispensed by Pump Action; it doesn't need squeezing or gravity.
[image: Bottle of eyedrops]

I usually must instill eyedrops myself; nobody can help me. But I miss too often.

#### Method 1: Vertical drop in eyes, while staring at the ceiling and lying on my back.

1.1. I wash my hands.

1.2. I lie flat on my back (on the couch or ground). I then stare at the dispenser's opening.

1.3. [My right eye (OS) is dominant](https://www.diyphotography.net/a-neat-trick-to-determine-your-dominant-eye/). So I  instill left eye first (OD), while keeping open OS:

[image: Instruction diagram]

1.4. After closing both eyes for 5 mins, I keep OS  open when instilling OD.

1.5. Difficulty: The drop lands on an eyelash, or the Upper or Lower Eyelid.

#### Method 2: Squirt in eyes, while standing and in front of mirror.

2.1. I stand in front of a mirror to witness my aim.

2.2. Same as 1.3. I aim the dispenser at the caruncle:

[image: Image of actual application of drops]

2.3. Difficulty: Because I'm standing, most of the drop falls out the eye.

Answer (score 1):

I usually apply eyedrops while standing, and looking up. No need to lie down.

For the left eye:

1. Tilt your head back as far as you can.
2. Use your thumb to hold down the lower eyelid, and the forefinger to hold the upper eyelid. This keeps you from blinking and provides a visual reference.
3. Use your right hand to hold the eyedropper.
4. Position the eyedropper: when looking straight up, you should be looking along the nozzle of the eyedropper. Your left hand gives a visual reference: the eyedropper should be just above your left thumb. Note the distance between your thumb and the nozzle. Try a few times until you get the distance right, then remember this distance for next time.

Answer (score 1):

As a contact lense wearer, I modified the method for inserting a contact lense for this purpose. For me it works pertty great.

1. Pull your eyelids wide open with your forefinger and middle finger, with your palm being in the plane of your face. (In my experience this is much more effective and convenient than using your thumb- and forefinger.)
2. Face the sky with your head (no need to lie down), and stare straight forward, so your iris is around the center of your eye
3. Position the eyedrop where it's point is (blurredly) seen at the center of your field of vision. This means it's right above your iris. Bring it as close as you feel comfortable. With some experience this can be pretty close - centimeter close.
4. Apply the drop.
5. ???
6. Profit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use eyedrops, but it doesn't make sense to aim at the caruncle - this is the place where tears discharge and if you put the drop there it will, naturally, fall out immediately. (Keep in mind that the tear gland is located at the further top side of the eye and you want to mimick that as much as possible when you apply eyedrops.) So I'd suggest you stand in front of the mirror, draw your lower eyelid away from your eye and aim, in the pocket formed, at the furthermost side from the caruncle (so that the drops would spread well before discharging at the caruncle). Tilt your head back right after this if you think it's necessary.